# No matching client found for package name 'com.example.labbookingsystem'

Tags: java, android, firebase

I was building my first application for my graduation project, using android studio based on java, and connected my project to firebase so I can save the registration data in firebase, then faced a problem regarding "google-services.json" file that I must download into my project, which I did along with some other lines in this directory "Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle):", following the instructions on Firebase console, after I finished all these steps I synced the project.
that's when my app won't run any more and show me this error every time I run it:

- What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.example.labbookingsystem'

Please help.

Comment: What is your app id in `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, please to improve your question add some of your code to show what you did and help others understanding your problem.

Comment: @NazariiMoshenskiy It is (Module: app).

Comment: @Gianmarco Thank you, there is no code included, it is kind of Android Studio problem that I have faced when I tried to link my project to FireBase.

Comment: @eMJay i meant this line in build.gradle `applicationId "com.example.safehouselab01"`. maybe your app id in firebase doesn't match app id in android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Firebase side, if you changed the name in the android studio nothing will happen, because I did.
But what worked for me is to create a new app in Firebase console with the same name from the error message that kept appearing every time I tried to run my app:
"No matching client found for package name "com.example.labbookingsystem",
which in my case will be "com.example.labbookingsystem".

Credit for the solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D0RGXSAhL0

Note: it is in 480p but it is worth it.